# How can I run the emacs daemon only when needed?

Tags: emacs

From what I have read, one way to speed up the emacs startup is to run `emacs --daemon` on login and then open files using `emacslient` instead of `emacs`, which will access the running emacs server instead of creating a new emacs instance.

However, I prefer to not put proframs in my autostart unless absolutely necessary, as a way yo speed up the login process. Is there a robust way to detect if an emacs server is running? This would let me write a simple script that would spawn the emacs server the first time I open a file with emacs.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if emacs_daemon_is_not_running # <-- How do I do this?
then
    emacs --daemon
fi
emacsclient -c "$@"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't even need to test if emacs is already running or not. `emacsclient` can start the emacs daemon if it's not already running. From `emacsclient(1)`:

```
   -a, --alternate-editor=EDITOR
          if the Emacs server is not running,  run  the  specified  editor
          instead.   This can also be specified via the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR'
          environment variable.  If the  value  of  EDITOR  is  the  empty
          string,  run `emacs --daemon' to start Emacs in daemon mode, and
          try to connect to it.
```

I use an alias, `ge`, for editing files, defined like this:

```
alias ge="emacsclient -c -n --alternate-editor=\"\""
```

Comment: For fractionally greater readability on that alias, it suffices to replace the `\"\"` with a space.  Alternatively, set the ALTERNATE_EDITOR environment variable (in a shell rc file, or if necessary in desktop environment settings), but set it blank, and then omit the `--alternate-editor=` part altogether.  `emacsclient` respects the difference between set-but-empty (where it invokes the daemon) and unset (where it fails).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `emacsclient` itself to test if there is a connection:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! emacsclient -e 0 >&/dev/null
then emacs --daemon
fi
emacsclient -c "$@"
```

`-e 0` means evaluate the expression "0", which just prints 0. The return code 
is non-zero if emacsclient fails to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in a shell function or script:

```
if ! ps h -o pid,args -C emacs | grep -q -- --daemon ; then
    emacs --daemon
fi
emacsclient -c "$@"
```

This assumes you are using the `ps` from the standard linux `procps` package.  If you are using another `ps`, the exact options will be different.

Comment: I went with `ps -e -o args | grep -q -- '^emacs --daemon$'`. It seemed simpler and more reliable.

Comment: yeah, the pid isn't needed - i only put it in there out of habit.  `ps -C emacs`, however, is more reliable than `ps -e | grep '^emacs'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ps` and `or`:

```bash
ps -e -o args | grep -qE 'emacs --(bg-|)daemon' || emacs --daemon
```

Inspired by `cas` and `hugomg` answer