# Is there a way to launch okular, emacs, etc. in order to have fast pop up at command line

Tags: emacs, okular

When I run emacs or okular from command line (these are two apps I use all the time) they are slow to launch.  Is there a way to just have them running and ask for new frames from the command line?

Comment: possibly related, for emacs: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237547

Comment: See [mupdf](https://mupdf.com/) for a faster sibling of okular.